# How to Hyperlink a SMB file contains special characters for Excel

Tags: apache-poi

I have a file, the file name contains some special characters, in my case square brackets, the file name is: [my]File.txt

I want to create a file hyperlink in Excel, I got a problem when I tired to link it as SMB address, the square brackets will be coded as %5B and 5%D instead of [], and I also tried to link it as local address, it does not have such problem.

Case 1 with local file, i.e. file saved under C:\[my]File.txt:

```
    File file = new File("c:\\[my]File.txt");
```

Case 2 with SMB Windows share, i.e. file saved under \\myServer\[my]File.txt:

```
    File file = new File("\\\\myServer\\[my]File.txt");
```

I create the hyperlink as following:

```
    Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.FILE);
    link.setAddress(file.toURI().toString());
    cell.setCellValue("open");
    cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

This is the pop-up info that I got when I hover the mouse onto the hyperlink cell in Excel:
[image: Pop-up in in Excel]

Comment: [File.toURI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI--) has known disadvantages when the abstract pathname represents a UNC pathname. Do using `link.setAddress(file.toPath().toUri().toString());` instead. That works for me.

Comment: Yes, this works also for me. Thanks very much, vielen Danke.